# New working copy created on git push hook

Tags: python, git, hook, githooks

I tried to write a hook with Python. I have a problem while executing it after a push. For example after a push the working copy should be reset. Reseting is executed but on the wrong folder. I get a new working copy after the push in the ".git" folder and not on the repo-folder. Can someone explain what happend?

```
process = subprocess.Popen("git reset --hard".split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

I am using the above code to reset the repo on the server side

Answer (score 0):

For the wrong folder problem:

My solution is to use Git hook installer which hardcodes the Git repository path in the hook script, so no matter where you run the commit hook script the commit hook script itself knows where the git repo folder is:

https://github.com/miohtama/vvv/blob/master/vvv/hooks/git.py